# Classification: a bayesian network for each class?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bayesian-network

Is there a technique for classification, where given a feature vector **X = (x_1, x_2,..., x_n)**

and a Bayesian network for each class, which for each **x_1, x_2,...,x_n** there may be a corresponding node in the network. So that I can classify whether the feature vector **X** belongs to the **"class"** represented by the network?

**Is this sort of strategy common?** does it work? It's hard to find something like it on the internet. The **motivation** behind the strategy is that I want to be able to **classify feature vectors** even when they have **missing features**, and also some features **only make sense with respect to some classes.**

**some background:**
This is an image classification project, where we have many feature extractors (each corresponding to an **x_i**) but they are costly to run. and some feature extractors only make sense to run on an image only to increase our confidence that that image belongs to a class.

I want to run a feature extractor, then check the confidences in each class and then based on those confidences choose another feature extractor and so on, until I am very sure that the image belongs to a particular class.